# Install grub on a disk drive by UUID

Tags: grub, nixos

There is a way to indicate to grub to install on a device MBR by UUID instead of using /dev/sdX ? I'm setting a external eSATA hard disk with NixOS, and obviusly, the hard disk not would be always the same /dev/sd*X* device ?

I see that I can config it with `boot.loader.grub.device = "/dev/sdX"`, but could set it to something like `"/dev/disk/by-uuid/...."`  ??

Comment: Your question is unrelated to programming and is off-topic here. Please go to SuperUser and ask there.

Comment: I didn't know SuperUser .. thanks! PD: Argg They don't have "nixos" tag!

Comment: Replicated at : http://superuser.com/questions/873947/install-grub-on-a-disk-drive-by-uuid

Answer (score -1):

**currently there is no support for what you want in nixos.**

see the respective source code here:
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-15.09/nixos/modules/system/boot/loader/grub/grub.nix

however, you should be able to use:

```
boot.loader.grub.device = "/dev/mydisk"
```

but you will need a **udev-ruleset** like this:

```
services.udev.extraRules = ''
  #Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", MODE="666", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB-odroid-u3-1"
  #Bus 003 Device 055: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", MODE="666", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB-odroid-u3-2"
  # Bus 003 Device 057: ID 054c:0268 Sony Corp. Batoh Device / PlayStation 3 Controller
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0268", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", MODE="0660", GROUP="users"
'';
```

but for your external harddrive of course. just **by using the symlink feature**.